# iPhone localization issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, localization

We recently added localization support to my app and added Hungarian translation. It was working fine. But then we found that some characters were not proper so I sent the ".strings" file to translator and replaced the old file with updated file.

Now, the localized string appears in alertbox but all screen/form/NIB displays English only.

I have no clue what went wrong in this process. It's kinda urgent and unfortunately my coder is not much responsive.

I am a programmer but not much familier with Objective C. If I can get some help from expert fellas, I might be able to solve it.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: A bit of code where you do this function would help us loads to help you. Better to post some of it in here.

Comment: Are the NIB's localized nib's ore are they localized from code with NSLocalizedString?

Comment: @V1ru8 yes, NIBs are localized. they were showing translated text before I replaced the translation file. could it be anyhting related to unicode characters in translation?

Comment: the .strings files should be in UTF-8 that's all. But do you have a separate nib file for every language? like `en.lproj/myui.xib` and `de.lproj/myui.xib` or do you have just one nib file and the localizations are set in code?

Comment: @V1ru8 there are seperate NIBs for most of screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was wrong exactly but I first restored that .string file with old version, opened it from Xcode and then replaced the content. One difference I observed was, there were two empty lines at EOF in old file, which was missing in new file, not sure if that caused the issue.

Thanks everyone!